# Get style settings in Roslyn Fixer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

At this moment I'm writing Roslyn analyzer with fixer that checks if constructor arguments are checked for null. And if not, fixer will add that check.
So, basically for code

```
public Foo(string param1)
{        
}
```

it should produce

```
public Foo(string param1)
{
    if (param1 == null)
       throw new ArumentNullException(nameof(param1));
}
```

But in some cases code style could be different and it is desired to get "if" with braces like

```
public Foo(string param1)
{
    if (param1 == null)
    {
         throw new ArumentNullException(nameof(param1));
    }
}
```

or even (not sure if there any settings for that, maybe I'll add separate fixer for it):

```
public Foo(string param1)
{
    this.param1 = param1 ?? throw new ArumentNullException(nameof(param1));
}
```

So, there are many options for a possible fix and I wonder - is it possible to read code style settings inside of fixer? I've checked

```
DocumentOptionSet options = context.Document.GetOptionsAsync()
```

but didn't found how to use it properly and not even sure that it is what I need. 
Will appreciate any tips and ideas

**UPDATE 1**
So, seem that I found how it is supposed to work:

```
options.GetOption(CodeStyleOptions.QualifyFieldAccess);
```

And I can see ([CSharpCodeStyleOptions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Workspaces/CSharp/Portable/CodeStyle/CSharpCodeStyleOptions.cs)) with needed option **PreferBraces**. However, this class is internal and I can't use it in fixer.

**UPDATE 2**
I tried `Simplifier.ReduceAsync()` method, but seem that it doesn't do what I need.

**UPDATE 3**
So, it seems that we all treat that property wrong, because of its naming. 
[Here is my issue in Roslyn github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29612). The main idea - "Prefer braces" option should be named "Require braces". [New issue for this change.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29621)
And it is not supposed to get these settings from analyzer/fixer code.